# MongoDB allocates chunks only to Primary when sharding is enabled

Tags: replication, mongodb, configuration, sharding

I'm setting up an instance of MongoDB with 3 shards. I've setup everything seemingly correctly by following the docs and comparing my config with that of a friend who has a similar setup but with a lot more shards.

The problem is that as soon as I shard a collection, db.collection.findOne() stops working and returns

```
2016-02-26T10:54:45.865+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "None of the hosts for replica set rs0 could be contacted.",
        "code" : 71
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:679:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:105:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:267:5
DBCollection.prototype.findOne@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:215:12
@(shell):1:1
```

Here's the process I followed.

```
use testdatabase
sh.enableSharding("testdatabase")
```

This step returns

```
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Then I do

```
sh.shardCollection("testdatabase.testcollection", {"testId": "hashed"})
```

Which returns

```
{ "collectionsharded" : "testdatabase.testcollection", "ok" : 1 }
```

At this point I do

```
sh.status()
```

on the config server, which lists all the shards and number of active mongoses correctly. This is its output:

```
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("56a242fbc6293301b0ad4dfd")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/pln126.example.com:27017,pln127.example.com:27017" }
        {  "_id" : "rs2",  "host" : "rs2/pln128.example.com:27017,pln129.example.com:27017" }
        {  "_id" : "rs3",  "host" : "rs3/pln130.example.com:27017,pln131.example.com:27017" }
  active mongoses:
        "3.2.1" : 3
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
        Last reported error:  Need to swap sharding catalog manager.  Config server reports that it is in replica set mode, but we are still using the legacy SCCC protocol for config server communication
        Time of Reported error:  Fri Feb 26 2016 15:58:07 GMT+0100 (CET)
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "testdatabase",  "primary" : "rs1",  "partitioned" : true }
                testdatabase.testcollection
                        shard key: { "testid" : "hashed" }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                rs1     3
                        { "testid" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "testid" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258602") } on : rs1 Timestamp(1, 0)
                        { "testid" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258602") } -->> { "testid" : NumberLong("3074457345618258602") } on : rs1 Timestamp(1, 1)
                        { "testid" : NumberLong("3074457345618258602") } -->> { "testid" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs1 Timestamp(1, 2)
```

Please, note that the "Need to swap sharding catalog manager." error goes away if I change the format of mongos config file. Currently, it's in the following format - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
But that error disappears if I change it to a different format (couldn't find it online), but the change would be something like this

```
security:
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile
  keyFile: /etc/mongod.key
```

would change to

```
keyFile=/etc/mongod.key
```

and I would not get that error anymore, even if the mongod configs for the other servers are still in the first format as described in the mongodb docs.

But when changed to a different one. E.g. from 
So basically it's placing all the chunks in the primary and won't let me do any queries on the collection. However, if I try to login to mongo on one of the config servers or one of the shards, I connect successfully.

Any ideas? Or do you need more info or something?

Thanks.

EDIT:

As requested, here's the result of `rs.status()`

```
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:59.977Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(7),
        "configsvr" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "pln135.example.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 20162,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1456498319, 9),
                                "t" : NumberLong(7)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:59Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1456478170, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-02-26T09:16:10Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "pln136.example.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 20147,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1456498312, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(7)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:52Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:58.352Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:58.351Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                        "syncingTo" : "pln137.example.com:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "pln137.example.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 20160,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1456498312, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(7)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:52Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:58.683Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-02-26T14:51:58.682Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "syncingTo" : "pln135.example.com:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Please, bear in mind, I've configured the port to be that one, it's not a mistake. I've also replaced my domain with "example" for privacy concerns.

Current `mongos.conf` on the App Servers.

```
sharding:
  configDB: "pln135.example.com:27017,pln136.example.com:27017,pln137.example.com:27017"
security:
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile
  keyFile: /etc/mongod.key
```

Alternative `mongos.conf` I've tried which doesn't give the "Need to swap sharding catalog manager."

```
configdb=rs0/pln135.example.com:27017,pln136.example.com:27017,pln137.example.com:27017
keyFile=/etc/mongod.key
```

Here's a `mongod.conf` from the config servers

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

#processManagement:

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /etc/mongod.key
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0

sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Here's a `mongod.conf` from a shard.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

#processManagement:

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /etc/mongod.key

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs1

sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: `"None of the hosts for replica set rs0 could be contacted."` is more than just a subtle hint what might be wrong. You want to check that each node in the cluster can resolve the name you used in the replica set configuration for the members. Furthermore, you need to make the according ports accessible. Please add the output of `sh.status()` and `rs.status()` for rs0 to your question.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I've added the output of those commands as you requested. I've also created a new chain in IP tables allowing all of my servers and that port, which I could lock down a bit more later if I can get this working for security measures. But for now, even like this doesn't work. Also, I can log in from the App Server to the config server via `mongo -u root -p xxx --authenticationDatabase admin hostOfConfigServer:27017`

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I upgraded MongoDB from 3.2.1 to 3.2.3 and it magically started working. I didn't even need to recreate / reconfigure anything. It just started splitting the chunks correctly and works fine.